# Yii - SQLSTATE[HY000] but query executed

Tags: sql, yii, phpmyadmin

I tried to execute a multiple SQL insertion in my Yii application:

```
INSERT INTO take_lf (data, start, end) 
VALUES ('take1.csv', '0', '0'), ('take2.csv', '0', '0'), ('take3.csv', '0', '0')
```

The query is executed (I could see the result on PhpMyAdmin) but I got an error on Yii:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? I looked for the PhpMyAdmin log on Status->Monitor but I didn't find anything.

EDIT: the trace is the following.

```
#0 /volume1/web/yii/framework/db/CDbCommand.php(395): CDbCommand->queryInternal("fetchAll", array(2), array())
#1  /volume1/web/dbcremona/protected/controllers/TakeLF.php(253): CDbCommand->queryAll()
251         }    
252         $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1); //tolgo ultima virgola
253         $r = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();**    
254         echo $r;
255     }
256 
257     /**
258      * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
#2  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(49): TakeLFController->actionInsert_multiple()
#3  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("r" => "takeLF/insert_multiple"))
#4  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(133): CController->runAction(CInlineAction)
#5  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilter.php(40): CFilterChain->run()
#6  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CController.php(1145): CFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#7  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/filters/CInlineFilter.php(58): CController->filterAccessControl(CFilterChain)
#8  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/filters/CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter(CFilterChain)
#9  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
#10  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(CInlineAction, array("accessControl", "postOnly + delete"))
#11  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run("insert_multiple")
#12  /volume1/web/yii/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController("takeLowFeature/insert_multiple")
#13  /volume1/web/yii/framework/base/CApplication.php(169): CWebApplication->processRequest()
```

Comment: Can you post the exception trace?

Comment: Hi, I edited my post, I don't know if that's what you meant.